# Knockout with jQuery tmpl rendering unparsed templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, jquery-templates, knockout-mvc

I referenced the jQuery tmpl like this:

```html
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Furthermore, I referenced KnockoutJS like this:

```html
 <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I then have a small snippet of code like this:

```html
<div data-bind="template:'partnersTemplate'"></div>
<script id="partnersTemplate" type="text/html">
<ul>
    {{ each(index,par) partners}}
        <li> ${par.name} </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

Why does the browser not show me a *rendered* template? It shows me the brackets and literally all that content.

Comment: Are you using durandal ?

Comment: Did you include jQuery before including tmpl? Either way, this is a guessing game for us. You'll have to debug this yourself (for starters, open a console to check for JS errors) and edit the question with more details.

Comment: What does your viewmodel look like?

Comment: what are the usually  steps in order to use this templates?and combined with knockout...then i'll be able to verify things,maybe it's not so clear to me something.and by the way,i am only using the example showed by Steve Sanderson when he presents the knockout with person and friend client view-models.i only changed the friend to partner,the rest is the same

Comment: function partner(name) {
        return {
            name: ko.observable(name)
        };
    }

    var viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable("jon doe"),
        address: ko.observable("street no 1"),
        partners: ko.observableArray([new partner("Johnny"), new partner("Amie")]),
        addPartner: function () {
            this.partners.push(new partner('another'));
        }};

Comment: also the syntax i wrote is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<div data-bind="template:'partnersTemplate'"></div>
```

To this:

```
<div data-bind="template:{ name: 'partnersTemplate' }"></div>
```

Comment: i tried this also,but the question is what do i need normally to work,because it  seems that he doesn't recognize at all the syntax for jquery templates.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would be required to use jQuery Templates and not the standard knockout templating?

Comment: i was following the example of Steve Sanderson,with person and friend,on knockout site,and there he doesn't mention anything about what to do in order to work the jquery templates,just that are most used in conjuction with knockout.so all i want is to finalize that example to work.